# Cannot run Shared Groovy library function

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am in the process of setting up Jenkins pipeline builds and am starting to use the same methods across multiple jobs, so it's time to put these common methods into a shared library.

The first function I have created is to update GitHub with the result of some unit tests. I am having an issue where I can run this function from the command line fine but when it comes to using it within my Jenkins build it does not work and I cannot seem to get any debug output in the Jenkins console

This is the directory structure of my shared library

```
my-project
src
vars
  - getCommitId.groovy
  - gitUpdateStatus.groovy
```

So the first function `getCommitId` works fine

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
def call() {
  commit_id = sh script: 'git rev-parse HEAD', returnStdout: true
  commit_id = commit_id.replaceAll("\\s","") // Remove Whitespace
  return commit_id
}
```

This returns the correct value

This is `gitUpdateStatus`

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7')

import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder


String targetUrl = 'https://api.github.com/repos/myRepo/'
def http = new HTTPBuilder(targetUrl)
http.request(POST) {
  uri.path = "repo/statuses/12345678"
  requestContentType = JSON
  body = [state: 'success', description: 'Jenkins Unit Tests', target_url: 'http://test.co.uk', context: 'unit tests']
  headers.'Authorization' = "token myOauthTokenHere"
  headers.'User-Agent' = 'Jenkins Status Update'
  headers.Accept = 'application/json'

  response.success = { resp, json ->
    println "GitHub updated successfully! ${resp.status}"
  }

  response.failure = { resp, json ->
    println "GitHub update Failure! ${resp.status} " + json.message
  }
}
```

I can run this fine via the command line, but I get no output when run as a Jenkins build.

My Jenkinsfile

```
@Library('echo-jenkins-shared')_
node {
  GIT_COMMIT_ID = getGitCommitId()
  echo "GIT COMMIT ID: ${GIT_COMMIT_ID}"
  gitUpdateStatus(GIT_COMMIT_ID)
}
```

Why would this not work or could this be converted to just use native Groovy methods?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would advise you to use as service like https://requestb.in to check if your code actually perform HTTP calls.

Second, I would recommend NOT to use `@Grab`-based dependencies like `HTTPBuilder` in Jenkins pipelines, but the `http_request` plugin instead, downloadable & installable as a `.hpi`:
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/

Finally, you can find an example of utility class to perform HTTP requests here:
https://github.com/voyages-sncf-technologies/hesperides-jenkins-lib/blob/master/src/com/vsct/dt/hesperides/jenkins/pipelines/http/HTTPBuilderRequester.groovy
With the rationale behind it explained there: https://github.com/voyages-sncf-technologies/hesperides-jenkins-lib#httprequester

Comment: Thanks for the information, I can confirm that my code does actually perform HTTP calls, which is a start i guess, GET requests working fine, just the POST i am having problems with a minute